# How to move multiple objects in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Me and my classmates are trying to make a code that will move all the objects at the same time. We have a class Picture and inside we have variables: `car, wheels, cabin, driver`.

When we use a for loop they move one after another. What we need is to make them move all at the same time. Can you suggest a loop that will work for all at the same time, because what we get now is 1st line is executed and the other are left over. After is done it moves to the next line.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Picture
{

    private Square wall;
    private Square window;
    private Triangle roof;
    private Circle sun;
    private boolean drawn;
    private Circle wheels;
    private rectangle body;
    private Square cabin;
    private Person driver;
    private Circle wheels2;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Picture
     */

    public Picture()
    {
        wall = new Square();
        window = new Square();
        roof = new Triangle();  
        sun = new Circle();
        drawn = false;
        wheels = new Circle();
        wheels2 = new Circle();
        driver = new Person();
        cabin = new Square();
        body = new rectangle();

    }

    /**
     * Draw this picture.
     */
    public void draw()
    {
            driver.changeSize(80, 60);
            driver.moveHorizontal(30);
            driver.moveVertical(30);
            driver.makeVisible();

            body.changeSize(220, 60);
            body.moveHorizontal(10);
            body.moveVertical(20);
            body.makeVisible();

            wheels2.changeSize(60);
            wheels2.moveHorizontal(130);
            wheels2.moveVertical(10);
            wheels2.makeVisible();

            wheels.changeSize(60);
            wheels.moveHorizontal(10);
            wheels.moveVertical(10);
            wheels.makeVisible();

            cabin.changeSize(60);
            cabin.moveHorizontal(10);
            cabin.moveVertical(20);
            cabin.makeVisible();

            while(true)
               {

                 driver.slowMoveHorizontal(100);
                 body.slowMoveHorizontal(100);
                  wheels.slowMoveHorizontal(100);
                  wheels2.slowMoveHorizontal(100);
                  cabin.slowMoveHorizontal(100);

                driver.slowMoveHorizontal(-100);

                body.slowMoveHorizontal(-100);

                wheels.slowMoveHorizontal(-100);

                wheels2.slowMoveHorizontal(-100);

                cabin.slowMoveHorizontal(-100);

            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Change this picture to black/white display
     */
    public void setBlackAndWhite()
    {
        wall.changeColor("black");
        window.changeColor("white");
        roof.changeColor("black");
        sun.changeColor("black");
    }*/


    /**
     * Change this picture to use color display
     */
    public void setColor()
    {
        wall.changeColor("red");
        window.changeColor("black");
        roof.changeColor("green");
        sun.changeColor("yellow");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need some parallelism. You can move each component in a different thread. But this also would not ensure complete parallelism, but it would be at least better than your sequential operations.

Comment: As is, the simplicity in this answer is misleading. AWT and swing only do painting via the event dispatch thread (see the [swing concurrency documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)). Simply saying “use multiple threads” without understanding the correct threading model is going to lead to more problems. To make this a good answer, I strongly suggest adding much more detail.